# DDoS through robots.txt?

Tags: apache-2.4, ddos

So today I noticed a high amount of apache requests on my webserver. Going through my log files, I saw that apparently one of my websites was targeted for a DDoS attack. Robots.txt was constantly requested by about a 1000 different IP addresses.

Now this really didn't cause any high traffic (robots.txt is only 200 bytes) nor was it straining apache (it could easily handle the number of requests). So I'm not entirely sure If this was like a really lame attempt at a DDoS attack, or something else is going on.

Is there something I'm unaware of why they specifically targeted robots.txt? If they wanted to bring the server down, why not simply target the home page instead?

Comment: It can be as simple as bad programming and a typo or logic error by somebody wanting to scrape the internet rather than intentionally  targeting your domain. - 

In bash for example: an array with domains 


   `Domains=(domain0 domain1 domain2)` and then 

    `for Domain in "${Domains[@]}" ; do echo "Get $Domain/robots" ; done`

versus 

   `for Domain in "${Domains[@]}" ; do echo "Get $Domains/robots.txt" ; done`

Comment: But from almost a thousand different IP addresses?

Comment: Jezus Christ. I so fucking hate serverfault - with a passion. Every single post I make is closed with some lame reason. WTF are you talking about this is opinion based?  WhaT opinion are you talking about. Seriously. The moderators here need to get down off their pedestal. Stop the fucking power trip